# Множество циклов PHP в один

Tags: php, циклы

Есть, например, число 48. Это число мы делим на 16 и получаем 3. Так вот, нужно три раза выполнить разный цикл, то есть обычно это будет выглядеть так:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
 ...
}

for($i = 16; $i < 32; $i++) {
 ...
}

for($i = 32; $i < 48; $i++) {
 ...
}
```

Мне же нужно не прописывать постоянно разные циклы, а сделать так, чтобы в каком-нибудь общем цикле делалось всё само.

Поможете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, где-то так (предполагаем, что делить нужно на три части):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 48; $i++) {
  $c = (int)($i / 16);
  switch ($c) {
    case 0:
       // 0-15
       break;
    case 1:
       // 16-31
       break;
    case 2:
       // 32-47
       break;
    default:
       // Ops!
  }
}
```

Если же количество "частей" заведомо неизвестно, то можно попробовать создать массив ссылок на нужные функции и в цикле все вызывать.

Comment: @KoVadim, немного не то. Если же я пропишу в промежутке 0-15, к примеру, echo 1, то отобразится всего-лишь одна единица, а не 123456789...

Или я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Я просто очень давно не писал на php, забыл одни скобки. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @KoVadim, гений!